# "Protocol error: Unknown protocol identifier" after changing FileZilla server admin interface port number

Tags: networking, ftp, filezilla

I have download FileZilla server and I am trying to create a server using the FileZilla software. I have used a new port add a user and from the FileZilla client I tried to enter to the server. Everything worked fine. However when I closed the FileZilla server and tried to reopen again I got the following:

> Connecting to server 127.0.0.1:port... 
>    Connected, waiting for authentication 
>    Protocol error: Unknown protocol identifier (0x50 0x50
>   0x48). Most likely connected to the wrong port. Connection to server
>   closed.

What is that issue? Now I cant use any option of FileZilla sotware from menu. Every option is marked on gray (unavailable) and I am receiving constantly this message.

EDIT: with the suggested answer from @Martin Prikryl I am receiving from the server interface the following:

> Connected, waiting for authentication
>   Logged on
>   Warning: FTP over TLS is not enabled, users cannot securely log in.

and from the client:

> Status:   Connecting to 127.0.0.1:12321...
>   Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
>   Response:   FZS
>   Response:   S
>   Response:   D
>   Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
>   Error:  Could not connect to server

Comment: How did you "close the filezilla server"? Where you got the error? In the FileZilla client? Or FileZilla server interface?

Comment: I terminate the service. The error is is the server interface.

Comment: In the management console? And you restarted the service there too?

Comment: What port did you change? The FTP port or the admin interface port?

Comment: Yes. After that I cant use the interface except the first pop up window in which you add the port.

Comment: Regarding the last message in your edit: What client? FileZilla FTP client? It looks like you are connecting with (FileZilla) FTP client to the administrative port. Now I'd say that you changed both FTP port and admin port to the same number, didn't you? So the service conflicts with itself.

Comment: Yes the FTP client. In the client interface I am giving host 127.0.0.1 userN and pass and the port that I have created in the server FTP.

Comment: Basically I am not familiar with all that staff. What is the difference between admin and FTP port?

Comment: There are two ports. The FTP port and the admin port. I'm not sure what port you are talking about. Show us some screenshots.

Comment: The admin port is used by the FileZilla Server interface to configure the FileZilla FTP service. The FTP port is the port you connect to with FTP client. They have to be different.

Comment: I have put the same port everywhere obviously. However I am not sure how to configure admin and ftp port.

Comment: *However I am not sure how to configure admin and ftp port.*  What is the question? You obviously know how to configure them, as you have changed these.

Comment: Hm I think I got it. The issue was something else. The issue was in IP filter I was choose to filter all the IP addresses except the IP of my machine. However it seems that I add it wrong.

Comment: I cannot be just that. You wouldn't get the error you were getting, had it been the IP filter. It might have been a combination of both though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31313/discussion-between-jose-ramon-and-martin-prikryl).

Comment: When I remove the filter, the connection with clinet worked. However now I cant connect from other IP only from the same PC.

Comment: That a different question. I believe I have answered your initial question. Please, consider accepting my answer and post a new question for your new problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there's another service running on the same port. *Or (as it turned out), you have configured FileZilla server with the same port number for both FTP port and admin interface port. So the FileZilla service conflicts with itself.*

Try to change the admin interface port to a yet another one (or back to the standard one, the 14147).

You can change it manually in
`C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla Server\FileZilla Server.xml` (64-bit path).

```xml
<FileZillaServer>
    <Settings>
        ...
        <Item name="Admin port" type="numeric">14147</Item>
        ...
    </Settings>
</FileZillaServer>
```

You should stop the service before changing the XML file and re-start afterwards.